# How to animate a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Is it possible to animate a JAVASCRIPT(not HTML) object with "CSS-style" transitions? For example, given an object: 
`class ball { constructor(x_pos, y_pos)}
let ball = new ball;`
is it possible to change this object's parameters with animation, sort of an animated translation?

Comment: You want to animate your code?

Comment: it seems you want to create a game, you could use a library like p5.js or create a canvas in HTML and draw and animate your object

Comment: You want to animate a text file?? I don't quite understand the concept O_o

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have a javascript code for colliding balls(moving ball objects), and by clicking a button these should stack on top of each other creating a sort of a chart... but is there a way to get them "gradually" piling up? To get the thing a bit more "visual" and graphic...